# async await function returns promise instead of string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am new to javascript , Here I have a following `graphql`

```
 getId = async dataId => {
    let finalData = await apolloClient.query({
      query: GET_DOOR_ORDER,
      variables: {
        Id: dataId
      }
    })

    return finalData?.value
  }
```

Now, I am calling this function

```
   let orderIdForbuyingSessionsEdit = '';

  orderIdForbuyingSessionsEdit = this.getClientOrderIdFromDoorOrder(orderId)
```

This gives an error

```
Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How do I get string as a return value from a async function.

Comment: You have to `await this.getClientOrderIdFromDoorOrder(orderId)`

Comment: An `async function` *always* returns a promise, that's their entire purpose. You'll still need to wait for the result.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call async functions you need to put `await` keyword where you make a call. This will *wait* till promise is resolved and return the value.

In the text of your question, the first `getId` function is a good example of the async function call. You need to do the same in place where you call it too:

1. function where you call another async function should have `async` keyword prefix
2. async function which is going to be called should have an `await` keyword prefix

So in order to call your `getId` function properly somewhere you need to act like this:

```
async function myMethod() {
   let value = await getId(123);
   console.log(value);
}
```

Read more about async/await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).